# Jenkins Integration with Automic for Pipeline Script

Tags: maven, jenkins, deployment, automation, jenkins-pipeline

We are currently working on Continuous Delivery pipeline implementation for our team.  Our approach is to push the deployable to Nexus from Jenkins and then pull from Nexus with Automic to deploy to our target environment.  The major reason for this is currently automic deployment is automated and in place. We just want to reuse the existing deployment process and integrate it with the new CD Pipeline script that we are writing.

We are facing a challenge with a backward handshake from Jenkins -> Automic. Could you please let me know if any of you have already explored this and can help us with some inputs on this. We are able to trigger an automic workflow using a freestyle job in Jenkins from Pipeline. However we are not sure how could our pipeline resume after receiving a Success/failure status of the deployment workflow.

Our Current Approach

1. Jenkins Pipeline Script use a freestlye job to call automic workflow to trigger a deployment to our target environment. We pass few parameters that are required to trigger that automic job from jenkins.
2. Our Jenkins Pipeline script wait here for the next steps to be proceeded after deployment is successful. If deployment fails the pipeline should abort there. Could you please let me know if there is a known integration mechanism in which automic can send jenkins a status on the job it triggered.

Appreciate quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

some clue you can try:-

Regarding Jenkins and Automic connection, you can have a shell/perl scripts in place where you can accept input from users like Automic URL, password, workflow name etc.. that should probably  help you in Jenkins-Automic Integrtion

Also, it is fairly possible to integrate Automic-Jenkins from Automic ARA using jenkins custom actions.

Regarding workflow status, you can  connect to automation engine database using SQL clientn from Jenkins and continuously check for workflow status (Completed, Finished, Failed) and accordingly